# Close an Android app from View Class

Tags: android

Im creating a View object and set it as the content view on activity. Inside the view class i have drawn some images such as next and exit.

So can any one suggest me how to terminate or stop the current activity from View class. I dont want it to be run in background. But it is okay to run in background until system cleans it out as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `finish()` on the activity. So, your view should be aware of activity it is shown in.

Comment: im using "onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me)" inside view class. From there i cant call "finish()". Can you please suggest how to call it.

Comment: You should pass an instance of your activity to the view's constructor.